# writing a code to open 2 CSV using (readline() or r) files and compare and display where they match

Tags: python

Contents on one of the csv files:

[image: contents on one of the csv files]

Need output display:

[image: need output display]

```
filename="student roster example.csv" #assign variable to student csv file

with open("student roster example.csv", "r") as file:
    roster=[line.rstrip() for line in file]

    print(roster)

with open("Program codes.csv","r") as courses:
    courses=[line.rstrip() for line in courses]

    print(courses)
```

This is my current code which is displaying all of the contents in both files.

Comment: You question is not clear. Please show the content of the 2 files that have to be compared. Also, please include the part of your code where you do the comparisson.

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/20170164).